# bootstrap p value in STATA

Tags: p-value, stata, bootstrap, matching

I have create a matrix with bootstrap estimation of the ATT.

First I extract a sample using bsample command with cluster , then I estimate the  propensity score ,and the ATT using the psmatch2 (with kernel option), and finally I save the result in a matrix.

```
In matrix form
```

#delimit ;
matrix input mymat=(0.1518 \
0.1406 \
0.1162 \
0.1222 \
0.0841 \
0.1578 \
0.2332 \
0.09 \
0.1362 \
0.1478 \
0.1984 \
0.1706 \
0.2553 \
0.0375 \
0.1081 \
0.1719 \
0.1873 \
0.0904 \
0.1259 \
0.1782 \
0.0761 \
0.1202 \
0.1353 \
0.072 \
0.1219 \
0.0915 \
0.0482 \
0.1197 \
0.0557 \
0.1192 \
0.1138 \
0.1516 \
0.096 \
0.1999 \
0.0502 \
0.1458 \
0.2614 \
0.1882 \
0.1613 \
0.1496 \
0.1719 \
0.1361 \
0.1496 \
0.1111 \
0.2091 \
0.0939 \
0.1053 \
0.1339 \
0.0633 \
0.044 \
0.1965 \
0.1847 \
0.1415 \
0.1367 \
0.2746 \
0.0844 \
0.0699 \
0.0881 \
0.1399 \
0.0481 \
0.1454 \
0.0721 \
0.0571 \
0.0902 \
0.1602 \
0.1352 \
0.0597 \
0.1764 \
0.0704 \
0.1703 \
0.1994 \
0.0313 \
0.2192 \
0.0511 \
0.1771 \
0.1828 \
0.1367 \
0.1496 \
0.1656 \
0.1847 \
0.1081 \
0.2596 \
0.0546 \
0.1651 \
0.1315 \
0.1104 \
0.1102 \
0.2174 \
0.0487 \
0.1384 \
0.0824 \
0.1121 \
0.0275 \
0.2632 \
0.1299 \
0.1135 \
0.194 \
0.2056 \
0.1198 \
0.2419 );

Or in dta file

```
input ATT 
  0.1518
  0.1406
  0.1162
  0.1222
  0.0841
  0.1578
  0.2332
  0.09
  0.1362
  0.1478
  0.1984
  0.1706
  0.2553
  0.0375
  0.1081
  0.1719
  0.1873
  0.0904
  0.1259
  0.1782
  0.0761
  0.1202
  0.1353
  0.072
  0.1219
  0.0915
  0.0482
  0.1197
  0.0557
  0.1192
  0.1138
  0.1516
  0.096
  0.1999
  0.0502
  0.1458
  0.2614
  0.1882
  0.1613
  0.1496
  0.1719
  0.1361
  0.1496
  0.1111
  0.2091
  0.0939
  0.1053
  0.1339
  0.0633
  0.044
  0.1965
  0.1847
  0.1415
  0.1367
  0.2746
  0.0844
  0.0699
  0.0881
  0.1399
  0.0481
  0.1454
  0.0721
  0.0571
  0.0902
  0.1602
  0.1352
  0.0597
  0.1764
  0.0704
  0.1703
  0.1994
  0.0313
  0.2192
  0.0511
  0.1771
  0.1828
  0.1367
  0.1496
  0.1656
  0.1847
  0.1081
  0.2596
  0.0546
  0.1651
  0.1315
  0.1104
  0.1102
  0.2174
  0.0487
  0.1384
  0.0824
  0.1121
  0.0275
  0.2632
  0.1299
  0.1135
  0.194
  0.2056
  0.1198
  0.2419
  end
```

I can found easily an IC

```
  quietly:sum ATT ,detail
  display "90% CI: [ " round(`r(p5)',0.001) , round(`r(p95)',0.001) "]"
```

90% CI: [ -.163 ,-.066]

My question is how can I find a p-value   $ [ H_0) E(Y_1-Y_0| Treated)=0 ]$

Here are some thoughts, using:  http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rbootstrap.pdf

```
  local NBootstrap   100            /* k */
  local ATTObserved -0.128
```

$\bar{\theta}$

```
  quietly : sum ATT
  local aux           =  r(mean)
```

$ \hat{se}=  \{ \frac{1}{k-1} \sum ( \hat{\theta_i}-\bar{\theta} )^2\} ^{1/2}$

```
  gen auxvar          = (1/(`NBootstrap'-1)) *(ATT-`aux')*(ATT-`aux') 
  quietly : sum auxvar
  local SDBootstrap=sqrt( r(sum) )
```

t-test

```
  gen ttestvar=  (ATT- `ATTObserved' )/`SDBootstrap'

  local ttesobserved (`ATTObserved') /`SDBootstrap'

  display "Bias" `ATTObserved'-`aux'
```

Bias             -.012436

```
  display " ttest observed" `ttesobserved'
```

ttest observed   -4.3199073

```
  count if abs(ttestvar) > abs(`ttesobserved') & ATT!=.
```

0

```
  drop auxvar ttestvar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code/general approach is pretty hard to follow. Here's how I might do this, which may contain the ingredients for your own solution:

```
clear all
webuse cattaneo2, clear
/* Define Your Own BS Program */
capture program drop mybs
program define mybs, rclass
psmatch2 mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, outcome(bweight) ate
return scalar att = r(att)
return scalar ate = r(ate)
end

bootstrap  att = r(att) ate = r(ate), reps(500) saving("PSM_ATEs.dta", replace): mybs
estat bootstrap, all

/* For Comparison */
psmatch2 mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, outcome(bweight) ate
```

You might also consider using Stata's own matching command, which accounts for the estimation of the PS in its standard errors (so no bootstrapping is needed):

```
teffects psmatch (bweight) (mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, probit), atet
teffects psmatch (bweight) (mbsmoke mmarried c.mage##c.mage fbaby medu, probit), ate
```

Comment: Thank @Masterov for your reply. I use psmatch2, because I use the option kernel. And I create my own code to do bootstrap, because I want to estimate the score every time I make a bootstrap. I am not sure if I can do this with the command bootstrap of STATA

Comment: @EAguirre My code estimates the score each time it does a rep. With kernel matching, the `teffects psmatch` will not work. Did this help with your problem?

Comment: You are genious . Thanks!  I artificially create a cluster var:                       generate clustervar = rbinomial(50,0.05) ; then I call your command with the cluster option  ,                                                                                        set seed 123
bootstrap  att = r(att) ate = r(ate), ///
reps(5) saving("PSM_ATEs.dta", replace): mybs ///
estat bootstrap, all cluster(clustervar) strata(mbsmoke)

Comment: @EAguirre I am not sure why you need the clustering part. The bootstrap should take care of that for you. Don't be alarmed if each time you run mybs is gives you the same answer. When you use the bootstrap prefix with it, the sampling is done for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !. I added the cluster (schools) because I am evaluating an educational program (my unit of analysis are students) and I want to correct the SE for this

Comment: @EAguirre I am not sure that accomplished that, but I am not an expert. Might be worth a separate question, either here or over at Statalist.